# Getting JSON.typeMismatch trying to convert string coming from an HTTP Get to JSON object

Tags: java, android, json

I have looked at multiple other answers here but I still have not been able to resolve this issue.

I call a PHP restful server to get a JSON string from a database. Here is the log output of the string that comes back:

> "{\"pat_list\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"John Deere\",\"gender\":\"M\",\"child\":\"N\",\"email\":\"mail@site.com\",\"patientid\":\"12657\",\"pridiag\":\"Sick\"}]}"

This looks like valid JSON (it validates) and looks properly escaped to me (it was created using json_encode in PHP on the server)

However, when I try to execute this code:

```
    if (json_pat_list != null) {

        Log.d("json_string",json_pat_list);

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json_pat_list);
```

I get:

> W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value {"pat_list":[{"id":"1","name":"John Deere","gender":"M","child":"N","email":"mail@site.com","patientid":"12657","pridiag":"Sick"}]} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject    ... W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)

Can anyone see what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems legit. As far as I can see. What I can suggest is that because you say that it is generated on the PHP server, it might be putting in characters that malformat the string completely.

There are 2 things I can suggest:

```
    if (json_pat_list != null) {

    Log.d("json_string",json_pat_list);

    //Either this

    String formattedString = json_pat_list.replaceAll("\n", "\\n");

     //or you can do this
     String formattedString = json_pat_list.substring(s.indexOf("{")); 

    try {

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json_pat_list);
```

Comment: definitely on the right track. I copied the string from the log and just fed it directly in and it parsed correctly. But neither of these suggestions got rid of whatever is screwing up the string.

Comment: Solved it. Thanks @TejjD for putting me on the right track. I ended up removing the leading and ending quotes and removing the "\"s that were escaping the quotes inside the JSON. Everything I read said that JSONObject should handle that, but for some reason not in this case.